# while loop with 2 conditions to assembly code

Tags: loops, assembly, while-loop, mips, conditional-statements

I want to convert a while loop like that:

```
i=0; 
while ( (s[i]!='t') && (i<=20) ) {
  d[i]=c[i];
  i++;
}
```

with 2 conditions to assembly code.
how can i do that?
below is the version with 1 condition in the while.

```
    #################################################
# lab3_3a.s                 #
# while loop    char!=ASCII 0           #
#################################################
    .text       
        .globl __start 
__start:            # execution starts here

    li $t1,0        # counter for string
    li $s0,'t'      # chararacter to end copy
while:  lbu $t0,string($t1) # load a character
    sb $t0,copy($t1)    # copy character
    beq $t0,$s0,end     # if character to end copy then exit loop
    addi $t1,$t1,1      # increment counter
    b while         # repeat while loop
end:    li $t2,0
    sb $t2,copy($t1)    # append end character to copied string
    la $a0,copy     # display copy
    li $v0,4    
    syscall
    li $v0,10       # exit
    syscall         
        .data
string:     .asciiz "Mary had a little lamb"
copy:       .space 80
```

thanks guys.

Comment: I won't write the code for you, but i can help you by telling that in assembly you'll need to check it twice - with JNE and JLE. Also, what are s, d, c ??

Comment: think how to do `if (s[i] != 't' && i<=20) i++` first then just replace the body @EvgenyKolyakov there's no `jne` and `jle` in MIPS

Comment: You should at least show the code you already have for one condition. And explain what you understand of `&&`s (presumed) short-circuiting behaviour.

Comment: s,d,c are arrays to store a string. 
I dont need the whole program, I only need the code for the 2 conditions while loop!

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc really!? Wow, progress is here :)

Answer (score 1):

So, you've already successfully inverted one of the conditions and used it to jump out of the loop. Does it occur to you that you can do the same for the other?

```
    li $t1,0        # counter for string
    li $s0,'t'      # chararacter to end copy
    li $s1,20       # count to end copy
while:  lbu $t0,string($t1) # load a character
    sb $t0,copy($t1)    # copy character
    beq $t0,$s0,end     # if character to end copy then exit loop
    bgt $t1,$s1,end     # if count exceeds limit then exit loop
    addi $t1,$t1,1      # increment counter
    b while         # repeat while loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0; 
while ( (s[i]!='t') && (i<=20) ) {
  d[i]=c[i];
  i++;
}
```

Would contain two bugs, if `s` would be defined as `char s[20];`, first the `(i<=20)` would be one-too-much. It's very unusual to use `<=` in array length tests, it may be still correct if `char s[21];` is defined, but then you have two different "magic numbers" in source, 20 and 21. And the second bug is, even if you have correct length test, the `(s[i]!='t')` will execute ahead of `i` validation, so at the last character you will have out-of-bounds access.

Anyway, that C be written in C in a bit more "assembly-like" way like this:

```
i=0;
while(true) {  // Your "b while" is doing this already
  if (20 < i) break;    // test length first, to avoid s[21] (out of bounds)
  if ('t' == s[i]) break; // test for "terminator" character
    //^^ Yoda notation, to catch typo like (s[i]='t') as error
  d[i]=c[i];
  ++i;  // pre-increment form is more accurate to your intent
        // As you don't need original value after incrementation
}
// breaks will jump here.
```

This should be easy to rewrite in assembly, try it...

---

edit: and your original assembly is not "while", but "do-while", i.e. copy of first byte will execute under all circumstances, which is not what the C example is doing.

---

edit2: meanwhile of course this assumes you know the boolean logic algebra, as every programmer has to. I.e. you know that:

```
!(A && B) <=> (!A) || (!B)
```